# RAW partition with Live CD, NTFS partition in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, ntfs

I have a Windows 7 disk with C letter mount point in NTFS. Windows 7 boot normally with NTFS partition mounted. All is normal. But!, when I boot with a Linux live-cd or other tools like HBoot or PMagic it shows the partition as RAW file system. It's like Windows 7 sets the NTFS system in the boot. I check the BIOS for some UEFI parameters (maybe, I don't know where to search).

Can you help with this?

Comment: Encryption would explain it. But Bitlocker is something that I think started with Windows 8. Are you using any third-party encryption with Windows?

Comment: I think Bitlocker started with Windows Vista Enterprise Ed. (so far!). But the question is: there is no Bitlocker preferences in the disk, although I have Windows 7 Enterprise Ed. installed on my computer, and the Bitlocker is available but disabled. So, I think it could be a hidden partition, and when Windows 7 is starting between BIOS and Windows startup, it defines the partition system and drive letters, permissions, etc.